# MacBook Air 2020, restarting unexpectedly

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, kernel-panic

My MacBook 2020 is restarting unexpectedly. It is doing so randomly and I cannot pinpoint anything that I am doing to cause this action. I've re-installed the OS (clean install) and performed a reset on the SMC and NVRAM.

I have information from a Crash, but I'm not sure if it can assist in helping me to identify the issue.

```
Machine-check capabilities: 0x0000000000000c0b
 family: 6 model: 126 stepping: 5 microcode: 166
 signature: 0x706e5
 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1060NG7 CPU @ 1.20GHz
 11 error-reporting banks
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out on cpu 0, NMI-ing
mp_kdp_enter() NMI pending on cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out during locked wait after NMI;expected 8 acks but received 1 after 547204 loops in 595200000 ticks
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800cdc6529): "Machine Check at 0x00007fff205bb3c9, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x0000000109f47000, CR3: 0x00000002d5778061, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0\n" "RAX: 0xacf399d8dc2d0046, RBX: 0x0000000380134d70, RCX: 0xb1d7b8d4c4143f50, RDX: 0x0000000000000000\n" "RSP: 0x000070000b3abe00, RBP: 0x000070000b3abe20, RSI: 0x0000000000000000, RDI: 0x00007fff809af790\n" "R8:  0x00000a901ac4255c, R9:  0x0000000001491b42, R10: 0x000070000b3abe68, R11: 0x00007ff299613a08\n" "R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0x00000003844fdc60, R14: 0x0000000000000001, R15: 0x00000003802fc9f0\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000000206, RIP: 0x00007fff205bb3c9, CS:  0x000000000000002b, SS:  0x0000000000000023\n" "Error code: 0x0000000000000000\n"@/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/e90674e518/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-7195.121.3/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:168
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffb0b078bba0 : 0xffffff800cc8e0dd 
0xffffffb0b078bbf0 : 0xffffff800cdd4f33 
0xffffffb0b078bc30 : 0xffffff800cdc552a 
0xffffffb0b078bc80 : 0xffffff800cc32a2f 
0xffffffb0b078bca0 : 0xffffff800cc8d8fd 
0xffffffb0b078bdc0 : 0xffffff800cc8dbf3 
0xffffffb0b078be30 : 0xffffff800d49d81a 
0xffffffb0b078bea0 : 0xffffff800cdc6529 
0xffffffb0b078bf90 : 0xffffff800d4a15ae 
0xffffffb0b078bfa0 : 0xffffff800cc3328f 

Process name corresponding to current thread: com.apple.WebKit.WebContent
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
20F71

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 20.5.0: Sat May  8 05:10:33 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.121.3~9/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 52A1E876-863E-38E3-AC80-09BBAB13B752
KernelCache slide: 0x000000000ca00000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff800cc00000
Kernel slide:      0x000000000ca10000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff800cc10000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800cb00000
System model name: MacBookAir9,1 (Mac-0CFF9C7C2B63DF8D)
System shutdown begun: NO
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 11615556062519
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x00000a90751fffa7
  Sleep   : 0x00000a8e79a042be 0x0000107c27a9fd63 0x00000a83b740a3a6
  Wake    : 0x00000a8e7ee92189 0x000010d481ef8242 0x00000a8e7ce59bd8
last started kext at 11561744261492: >!UAudio   405.39 (addr 0xffffff7fa77a6000, size 315392)
last stopped kext at 7971901591399: >!UAudio    405.39 (addr 0xffffff7fa77a6000, size 315392)
loaded kexts:
@filesystems.smbfs  3.6
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   122.1
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    4050.1
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.3.3
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.3.3
>pmtelemetry    1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
|IO!BSerialManager  8.0.5d7
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  1
>!ABacklight    180.3
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!A!IICLGraphics    16.0.4
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.433
>!ABridgeAudio!C    140.4
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>BridgeAudioCommunication   140.4
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!A!IICLLPGraphicsFramebuffer   16.0.4
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   556.100.11
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   1677.120.9
>!A!BModule 1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIeMac   1
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    311
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!UAudio    405.39
@plugin.IOAVBDiscoveryPlugin    940.4
@kext.triggers  1.0
>!AHIDKeyboard  224
>!AHS!BDriver   4050.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  8.0.5d7
>!AActuatorDriver   4440.3
>!AMultitouchDriver 4440.3
>!AInputDeviceSupport   4400.35
>!AGraphicsControl  6.3.3
|IOAVB!F    940.4
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    985.2
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOAudio!F  300.6.1
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IONDRVSupport  585.1
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.1.4
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@!AGPUWrangler  6.3.3
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
|IOAccelerator!F2   442.9
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.3.3
|IOGraphics!F   585.1
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.1.4
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  290.8.1
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AXsanScheme   3
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>IO!BHost!CPCIeTransport    8.0.5d7
|IO!BHost!CTransport    8.0.5d7
>!AConvergedIPCOLYBTControl 1
>!A!BDebug  1
>!A!BDebugService   1
>!AConvergedPCI 1
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!ABCMWLANCoreMac   1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
>!AMultiFunctionManagerMac  1
>corecapture    1.0.4
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$!AImage4   3.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   985.2
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 8.0.5d7
|IOReport!F 47
|IO!BPacketLogger   8.0.5d7
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  511.120.2
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  184.121.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  436.121.1
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  436.121.1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 11.1
@kec.Libm   1
```

Comment: Your panic log is missing the machine check bank dump and also shows a secondary IPI timeout. Since this is reproducible, can you check `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` for all other instances of files beginning with `Kernel` and ending in `.panic`? Please upload all of them to some place like http://www.pastebin.com and add the links to your message so that we can check the logs and see if any of them contain more info.

Answer (score 0):

is doing some beeps on startup? it could be some hardware issue.

do some hardware tests, follow this
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731